# How to set up server to use proxy to connect to internet?

Tags: apache, http, proxy

I'm having problems setting up an Apache web server to use our company proxy.

Our company proxy is proxy.mycompany.com:8080

By default, all traffic from servers to the outside is blocked.  We are required to use this proxy.

I am working on a webserver, and I want to use the mod_proxy in http.conf but I'm not sure where to put it.

The documentation seems to suggest in  VirtualHost  , but I'm not using any VirtualHosts.  I have one website served from  Directory "/var/www/html"

Where in http.conf would I put this line ?

```
 ProxyRemote * http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Apache doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyremote):

> Context:  server config, virtual host

So you have to put this in the httpd.conf or a virtual host conf as you like